# JPA Criteria API multiple collection join

Tags: jpa

Can multiple joins be a condition?

```java
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Game> query = builder.createQuery(Game.class);

final Root<Game> game = query.from(Game.class);
final ListJoin<Game, Store> store = game.join(Game_.stores);
final ListJoin<Game, Category> category = game.join(Game_.categories);
```

the second join (catetory) makes results different even if there is no predicates with it.

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join is an inner join by default. So the query will only select the games that have at least 1 category. Make it a left join, and it will select all the games (even those which don't have any category).